# How to pass a function pointer to an external program in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to write a wrapper around a C program so that I can call it from Python. I am using Cython to do this. The C function takes a callback function as an argument, but this call back function will only be known at run-time of the python program. I have been searching how to do this and it seems there is not simple solution but the following seems to work:

```
#python.py

libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("myfunc.so") #Callback function is defined in myfunc.so 
....
c_wrapper(libc.fun, ...)
```

.

```
#c_wrapper.pyx

cdef extern void mainfunction(void *F, ...) #The intial C function we are wrapping
ctypedef void (*myfuncptr) () 

def c_wrapper(f, ...) # our function pointer is passed to the wrapper as a Python object
    cdef myfuncptr thisfunc
    thisfunc = (<myfuncptr*><size_t>addressof(f))[0]
    mainfunction(thisfunc, ...)
```

This method works for C and FORTRAN functions (i am assuming it will work for most compiled languges) and Python functions (using C types), but it seems a little awkward. Is there any more simple way of doing this in Cython?

Thanks

*EDIT : I am unable to change the C library I am trying to wrap*

Comment: It would be nice if there is one. But if you don't get any, your proposed solution could be useful to other people. In that case, maybe you could rephrase it as a pair question/solution?

Comment: Ok, one thing I didn't get the first time, and thus my answer: the callback function may come from a C/FORTRAN library or it can be a Python native function. Is that the case?

Comment: @Ricardo, Thats correct. Sorry I may not have stated this explicitly. Basilcaly, if the function comes from either a C/FORTRAN library it is stored as a _FuncPtr object, if the function is writen in native Python it can be stored as CFunctionType (by using C types). I suppose what I am really asking is if there is any ellegant way to cast any/all of these into a C function pointer within the wrapper?

Comment: @Dan: Mmh... Just one thing. Is your `mainfunction` being loaded from a library too (ie. could it be loaded using `cdll.LoadLibrary`?)

Comment: @Ricardo Yes, it could be loaded like that... Are you suggesting I could wipe out Cython completely and just call the `mainfunction` from Python?

Comment: Well, you *can* wrap Python functions using `ctypes`! And you don't need to wrap `<_FuncPtr>` objects to pass them to other `<_FuncPtr>` objects, so...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>I guess you're aware of [this](http://wiki.cython.org/FAQ#IsitpossibletocallmyPythoncodefromC.3F)?</strike>

> Is it possible to call my Python code from C?
>
> Answer: Yes, easily. Follow the example in Demos/callback/ in the
>   Cython source distribution

So, knowing that you can dload your main function, let's take another approach. I wrote a couple of stupid functions to test this:

```
/* lib.c -> lib.so */
#include <stdio.h>

void fn1(void) {
        puts("Called function 1");
}

void fn2(void) {
        puts("Called function 2");
}
```

then, the function that takes the callback

```
/* main.c -> main.so */

typedef void (*callback)();

void mainfunction(void *F) {
        ((callback)F)();
}
```

Which can be passed directly from Python:

```
>>> from ctypes import cdll
>>> lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib.so')
>>> main = cdll.LoadLibrary('./main.so')
>>> main.mainfunction(lib.fn1)
Called function 1
>>> main.mainfunction(lib.fn2)
Called function 2
```

And now, let's wrap a Python function:

```
>>> from ctypes import CFUNCTYPE
>>> def pyfn():
...     print "Called the Python function"
... 
>>> CWRAPPER = CFUNCTYPE(None)

>>> wrapped_py_func = CWRAPPER(pyfn)
>>> main.mainfunction(wrapped_py_func)
Called the Python function
```

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo Cárdenes,

I have seen this example, it shows how to wrap a C API that has a callback interface, so that you can pass Python functions to it as callbacks.

This is a good example of how this problem could be solved if I had access to the C library I am trying to wrap, unfortunatly I cannot touch it. Thank you

Comment: @Dan: new answer, based on other assumptions.

Comment: Thanks,
Just a little question. Why is it importand that the `mainfunction` is loaded using dll as opposed to declaring it in Cython?

Also, have you have tried running this example and it ran without errors? It just seems that I had already tried a very similar technique inside of Cython and I put it down to the fact that the functions loaded using cdll are the wrong type to just hand over directly to our C function?
for example:
`>>> print lib.fn1`
`_FuncPtr object at 0x0000000`
`>>> print pyfn`
`function pyfn at 0x0000000`
`>>> print wrapped_py_func`
`CFunctionType object at 0x0000000`

Comment: Well, `ctypes` knows how to do the conversions between different native C functions, and helps you wrapping around the Python functions to send them as callbacks, so that's why. And yeah, I've tested it. What you see up there is mostly cut+paste from my console (minus return values)

Comment: OK, Cheers. Ill have a better look. I think I must have been over-confusing issues. Cheers again!

Comment: @Dan: the point here is that the native functions you pass just as pointers; `ctypes` doesn't even need to know their return type, or their arguments, as it is `mainfunction` the one using it. The important one is the wrapping around the Python defined functions, and there's where `CFUNCTYPE` will help you.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. I just dont get how we can seemlessly pass a python object to a function without any casting? I suppose my confusion is arising from this _FuncPtr object. I cant find any doc on it but I am assuming that if we pass the `_FuncPtr` object to the `mainfunction` then we are going to in fact be passing a pointer to that object? (instead of a pointer to the function itself). Am I incorrect with this? (you may have realised I am new to this Python stuff!!)

Comment: Of course, you're not passing the `_FuncPtr` directly. The `_FuncPtr` object is a thin wrapper that `ctypes` provides to do conversion back/forth when calling the function from inside Python. When passing a `_FuncPtr` as an argument to another `_FuncPtr`, it will strip the pointer to the function out of the object before passing it, of course, meaning that `mainfunction` will be calling a C/FORTRAN callback directly, without wrappers involved.

Comment: For the Python native functions, we get a `CFunctionType` object provided by `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE`, and what gets passed to `mainfunction` is a pointer to some glue code written in C that is the one doing all the interaction, dynamically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6700/discussion-between-dan-and-ricardo-cardenes)