# How to pass a function pointer to a C api in Python 3.8

Tags: python, c, function, api, pointers

I have a C API with a error message callback:

`extern void set_errcb(void (*errcb)(const char *));`

It is exposed to python with the python function:

`module.set_errcb(errcb)`

How do I pass a function pointer argument in python?

I tried this:

```
import module

def my_errcb(msg):
    print(msg)

module.set_errcb(errcb)
```

and I get this error:

```
TypeError: in method 'set_errcb', argument 1 of type 'void (*)(char const *)'
```

How to pass my callback to C? Can I do this? How else should I handle this case if this isn't possible?

Edit:
I found I could do something like this:

```
from ctypes import *

msgfunc = CFUNCTYPE(c_char_p)
module.set_errcb(msgfunc(errcb))
```

But I still get the same error as above:

```
TypeError: in method 'args_set_errcb', argument 1 of type 'void (*)(char const *)'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800838/how-to-pass-a-function-pointer-to-an-external-program-in-cython